# Passing a column name as an argument for KDB select query?

Tags: kdb

I would like to pass a column name into a Q function to query a loaded table.

Example:

```
getDistinct:{[x] select count x from raw}
getDistinct "HEADER"
```

This doesn't work as the Q documentation says I cannot pass column as arguments. Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When q interprets x it will treat it as a string, it has no reference to the column, so your output would just be count "HEADER".

If you want to pass in the column as a string you need to build the whole select statement then use [value](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/value/)

```
{value "select count  ",x," from tab"} "HEADER"
```

However, the recommended method would be to use a [functional select](https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/funsql/). Below I use [parse](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/parse/) to build the functional select equivalent using the parse tree.

```
/Create sample table
tab:([]inst:10?`MSFT`GOOG`AAPL;time:10?.z.p;price:10?10f)

/Generate my parse tree to get my functional form
.Q.s parse "select count i by inst from tab"

/Build this into my function
{?[`tab;();(enlist x)!enlist x;(enlist `countDistinct)!enlist (#:;`i)]} `inst
```

Note that you have to pass the column in as a symbol. Additionally the #:i is just the k equivalent to count i.

**Update for multiple columns**

```
tab:([]inst:10?`MSFT`GOOG`AAPL;time:10?.z.p;price:10?10f;cntr:10`HK`SG`UK`US)
{?[`tab;();(x)!x;(enlist `countDistinct)!enlist (#:;`i)]} `inst`cntr
```

Comment: If you want to group by multiple columns then you will need to remove the enlist, see update above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is actually working fully, just that i did not verify my input data i.e. csv correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: @DanDan4561 you can get around the need for two versions by using this trick: `((),x)!(),x`. It will return a list whether there's one or more than one

Answer (score 0):

To get the functional form of a select statement, I recommend using [buildSelect](https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/parse_trees_and_functional_forms.pdf). Also, reduce the scope of parenthesis, i.e. use `` enlist[`countDistinct] `` instead of `` (enlist `countDistinct) ``.